# Fetching all the related records laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have table with structure as

### User

```
id|name|is_active
```

### Event

```
id|user_id(foreign key from user table)|event_name|is_active
```

### Event User(Linked table for events and users)

```
id|user_id(from user table)|event_id(from event table)|is_active
```

### Record

```
id|user_id(from user table)|event_id(from event table)|value|is_active
```

I want to fetch all the related records of the user after login

```
User (Object)
   |- Event(Object)
        |- Record
   |-Event2(Object)
        |- Record
        |- Record
```

Please suggest a solution for this. I am using eloquent

As suggested I have used the answers but when providing the where condition I'm not getting the desired result
My Query

```
 $userDetail = $user->with('eventUsers.events.records')->whereHas('eventUsers', function ($query){
                $query->where('is_active', 1);
            })->first();
```

Here it is rendering all the results from evenusers. I want only the active eventUsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use eloquent relationshiop logic like below

In User model
    To get details of user event

```
    public function getEvent(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
    }
```

In Event Model
    To get details of record of event

```
    public function getRecord(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Record');
    }
```

Your final query

```
$user_details = User::with('getEvent.getRecord')->get();
```

Comment: please check my question. facing one more issue with where condition

Answer (score 0):

well first in your user model:

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(App\Event::class)->withPivot('is_active');
}
```

then in your event model:

```
public function records()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Record::class);
}
```

then you can fetch data like this:

```
$user = User::where('id', auth()->id())->with('events.records')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getAllEvents() {
    $results = User::with(['events','events.records'])->where('id',auth()->id());
    $events = $results->get();
}
```

**User.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model {

    public function events() {
        return $this->hasMany(Event::class, 'user_id');
    }

}
```

**Event.php**

```
<?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Event extends Model {

        public function records() {
            return $this->hasMany(Record::class, 'event_id');
        }

    }
```